# Move window of other process to another virtual desktop

Tags: c#, c++, windows-10, virtual-desktop

So I am implementing a win-tab-like interface under Windows 10. I trying to move window of other process to another virtual desktop. Using API from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31801402/api-for-windows-10-virtual-desktops) I can already move my own application to any desktop. But when I am moving other windows when calling MoveWindowToDesktop(IntPtr TopLevelWindow, Guid CurrentDesktop), I got E_ACCESSDENIED as return code. In [this Github project](https://github.com/Eun/MoveToDesktop) someone managed to hook a DLL to other process so user can trigger this function successfully.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using the com `VirtualDesktopManagerInternal`

This and it's reliant objects have different CLSID depending on the build version of Windows.

The example code here is highly cut down, with only ***just enough to function on Windows build 22000*** (in my case testing on Windows 11 it works fine).

You can see an immensely more detailed .NET library here that handles all Windows versions with virtual desktops:
[github VirtualDesktop](https://github.com/Grabacr07/VirtualDesktop)

Anyway, here is the minimal code that is tested and working on Windows 11.

COM Import section:

```
static Guid CLSID_VirtualDesktopManagerInternal = new Guid("c5e0cdca-7b6e-41b2-9fc4-d93975cc467b");
static Guid CLSID_IVirtualDesktopManagerInternal = new Guid("b2f925b9-5a0f-4d2e-9f4d-2b1507593c10"); //windows version 22000
static Guid CLSID_ImmersiveShell = new Guid("C2F03A33-21F5-47FA-B4BB-156362A2F239");

[ComImport]
[Guid("372e1d3b-38d3-42e4-a15b-8ab2b178f513")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IApplicationView { }
[ComImport]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
[Guid("6D5140C1-7436-11CE-8034-00AA006009FA")]
internal interface IServiceProvider10 { [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] object QueryService(ref Guid service, ref Guid riid); }
[ComImport]
[Guid("92ca9dcd-5622-4bba-a805-5e9f541bd8c9")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IObjectArray { uint GetCount(); [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] object GetAt(uint iIndex, in Guid riid); }
[ComImport]
[Guid("536d3495-b208-4cc9-ae26-de8111275bf8")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IVirtualDesktop { Guid GetID(); }
[ComImport]
[Guid("1841c6d7-4f9d-42c0-af41-8747538f10e5")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IApplicationViewCollection { IObjectArray GetViews(); IObjectArray GetViewsByZOrder(); IObjectArray GetViewsByAppUserModelId(string id); IApplicationView GetViewForHwnd(IntPtr hwnd); }
//windows 22000
[ComImport, InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), Guid("b2f925b9-5a0f-4d2e-9f4d-2b1507593c10")]
[System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
public interface IVirtualDesktopManagerInternal { int GetCount(IntPtr hWndOrMon); void MoveViewToDesktop(IApplicationView pView, IVirtualDesktop desktop); bool CanViewMoveDesktops(IApplicationView pView); IVirtualDesktop GetCurrentDesktop(IntPtr hWndOrMon); IObjectArray GetDesktops(IntPtr hWndOrMon); IVirtualDesktop GetAdjacentDesktop(IVirtualDesktop pDesktopReference, int uDirection); void SwitchDesktop(IntPtr hWndOrMon, IVirtualDesktop desktop); IVirtualDesktop CreateDesktop(IntPtr hWndOrMon); void MoveDesktop(IVirtualDesktop desktop, IntPtr hWndOrMon, int nIndex); void RemoveDesktop(IVirtualDesktop pRemove, IVirtualDesktop pFallbackDesktop); IVirtualDesktop FindDesktop(in Guid desktopId); }
```

Code to put in your method:

```
IServiceProvider10 shell = (IServiceProvider10)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(CLSID_ImmersiveShell));
IVirtualDesktopManagerInternal managerInternal = (IVirtualDesktopManagerInternal)shell.QueryService(CLSID_VirtualDesktopManagerInternal, CLSID_IVirtualDesktopManagerInternal);
int numberOfDesktops = managerInternal.GetCount(IntPtr.Zero);
IApplicationViewCollection applicationViewCollection = (IApplicationViewCollection)shell.QueryService(CLSID_IApplicationViewCollection, CLSID_IApplicationViewCollection);
            
//window you want to move
IntPtr hwnd = PutHwndOfTheWindowYouWantToMoveHere;
IApplicationView applicationView = applicationViewCollection.GetViewForHwnd(hwnd);

//virtual desktop you want to move to, in this example the desktop at index 0
uint virtualDesktopIndex = 0; //index of the virtual desktop you want ot move the window into
IObjectArray allDesktops = managerInternal.GetDesktops(IntPtr.Zero);
IVirtualDesktop firstVVD = (IVirtualDesktop)allDesktops.GetAt(virtualDesktopIndex, typeof(IVirtualDesktop).GUID);

//the move function
managerInternal.MoveViewToDesktop(applicationView, firstVVD);
```